# is it possible to read laravel ".env" file in debug mode?

Tags: laravel, security

i'm currently running a laravel script in cpanel in debug mode true. Is they any way if that somebody can  read my .env file? as it has got all the details

i want that env file to be hidden incase if someboady can read that file in debug mode

Comment: If someone finds a way to trigger an unhandled exception on your site the debug mode exception message usually includes environment variables. While this does not mean they can read your .env file, environment variables include the ones that are read from the .env file

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of your `.env` file is independent on the debug level configured on your app. What it does mainly is change the log level of responses. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/deployment#debug-mode):

> The debug option in your `config/app.php` configuration file determines how much information about an error is actually displayed to the user. By default, this option is set to respect the value of the `APP_DEBUG` environment variable, which is stored in your application's `.env` file.

For the visibility concerns you have: Just make sure that the exposed directory of your app is the `/public` one and not the root of your project. Otherwise, someone could access your `.env`, that usually is stored at the root.

Comment: OP doesn't explicitly say that debug mode is in their .env file. They just mention that debug mode is true so I would take that to mean that the debug entry in `config/app.php` resolves to true.